# Zend findDependentRowset An error occurred

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have three two classess

```
class Application_Model_Accounts extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name            = 'accounts';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Application_Model_Bugs');
}
```

And

```
class Application_Model_Bugs extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name            = 'bugs';

    protected $_dependentTables = array('Application_Model_BugsProducts');

    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'Reporter' => array(
            'columns'           => 'reported_by',
            'refTableClass'     => 'Application_Model_Accounts',
            'refColumns'        => 'account_name'
        ),
        'Engineer' => array(
            'columns'           => 'assigned_to',
            'refTableClass'     => 'Application_Model_Accounts',
            'refColumns'        => 'account_name'
        ),
        'Verifier' => array(
            'columns'           => array('verified_by'),
            'refTableClass'     => 'Application_Model_Accounts',
            'refColumns'        => array('account_name')
        )
    );


}
```

in index controll i am trying to run this code.

```
public function indexAction()
    {

      $accountsTable = new Application_Model_Accounts();
      $accountsRowset = $accountsTable->find(1234);
      $user1234 = $accountsRowset->current();
      $bugsReportedByUser = $user1234->findDependentRowset('Application_Model_Bugs');
}
```

and on line

```
$bugsReportedByUser = $user1234->findDependentRowset('Application_Model_Bugs');
```

I am getting this error

```
An error occurred
Application error
```

I am unable to findout the problem. How to fix this problem. and is there a way to get more developer friendly error in Zend rather then just getting this message "An error occured".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution for this problem. 
in .Htaccess file
enable the development mode by adding this line on top

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
```

This will show the complete error trace. 
Sorted

full working example of bugs code including db available here
http://phphints.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/zend-framework-finddependentrowset-and-findparentrow-demo/